# What exactly did Leia do?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, the-last-jedi, princess-leia

Spoilers for *The Last Jedi*:

> An explosion caused General Leia to be flung into space. We then see her hand move and the [Force Theme](https://youtu.be/EKRj3Un7PEg?t=38s) plays, implying some sort of Force use.

That much is clear. What is not very clear is

> what exactly she is using the Force to *do*. 
>  I assumed she was simply guiding herself towards safety. People don't actually immediately explode/implode/freeze/etc. when in space so to me it makes sense that all she would need to do is use the Force to nudge her body in the right direction and the inertia would carry her to the intended destination (because there's no friction in space). 
>  However I've seen others claim she was creating a force bubble of air or something, while still others say she pulled the rebel ship to her, and so on. 
> So my question is **do we know for sure what Leia used the Force to do?**

---

<sub>I *prefer* official sources that shed new light on the subject (like scripts/novelizations/interviews/etc.) rather than answers that just say "well I watched that scene and to me it looked like she was doing ___" (but I guess I'd accept either kind if the argument is compelling enough).</sub>

---

<sub>I'd argue that my question is different from the 'dupe' one. That one basically asks "*How* did she do it? Was that the force?" and its answer is essentially "Yes, it was the Force". 
 *My* question is "*What* did she do? Did she Force pull? Force push? Force-not-need-to-breathe? Force cocoon/shell/shield-filled with air? See what I'm saying? I think that makes my question sufficiently different. :D</sub>

Comment: Actually, there *is* friction in Disney *Star Wars* space. It's necessary to explain the space chase, though it opens a whole new can of worms.

Comment: @Null Is it really necessary to explain the chase? I just assumed all the vehicles were continually accelerating, just at the same rate.

Comment: @Valorum I'd argue that my question is different from the 'dupe' one. That one basically asks "_How_ did she do it? Was that the force?" and its answer is essentially "Yes, it was the Force". _My_ question is "_What_ did she do? Did she Force pull? Force push? Force-not-need-to-breathe? Force cocoon/shell/shield-filled with air? See what I'm saying? I think that makes my question sufficiently different. :D

Comment: I agree with @Valorum that this is a duplicate. The top answer on the other question has quotes from "official sources" that shed new light on the subject, and an in-universe explanation that Jedi can use the Force to withstand the vacuum and survive.

Comment: @ArthurDent [Disney says Star Wars space has an ether](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/177863/31936) to explain things like the visible drag on the Resistance spaceships despite the fact that an "ether" [contradicts other canon sources](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/102967/31936) and presents many other problems. I don't make the rules for this, I just report them and/or laugh at the ridiculous ones.

Comment: Furthermore, to Null’s point, when an answer as to what specific force manoeuvre Leia used becomes available, it would be answered on said question, making it a duplicate.

Comment: @Edlothiad - Precisely. That question already contains pretty much everything we know on the subject of what she did.