# How did Vader beat the Millennium Falcon to Bespin?

Tags: star-wars

I understand that Boba Fett could have worked out the Falcon's destination from it's bearing/trajectory, but if the Falcon is "the fastest hunk of junk in the galaxy", how did Vader manage to "Arrive just before [they] did"?

This implies Vader *beat* the Falcon to Bespin, doesn't it? how would he have been able to negotiate [the terms of the bounty](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17076/why-did-han-solo-end-up-with-jabba-the-hutt) with Boba, and then *still* beat the ship to Bespin?

Unless by "they" (as in "they arrived just before you did"), Lando is referring to the Empire as an entity, and not to they physical presence of the Empire as Manifest by Vader?

Anyone have any canon answer?

Comment: @DVK, I see what you're trying to compare, but I'm asking a different question: How did Vader *beat them* not how did they get there... although the answers yielded are comparible..

Comment: If the answers of two questions line up, for the purpose of this site, they are duplicates

Comment: The [rules for "duplicate" questions](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/3198/976) are based around the same answers, even if the question itself is different.

Comment: Nah, it's a straight up dupe. One answers the other.

Comment: I don't see how it's a duplicate. "Why couldn't they fly fast?" - "Their engine was broken", "How did they get to Bespin with a broken engine?" - "They had a backup engine". These are two different questions, even if one can put so much information in the answer to one of the questions that it answers the other question as well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With their primary hyperdrive the Falcon was indeed one of the fastest ships and faster than an ISD, but it was broken at the time. The whole reason they went to Bespin is because their primary hyperdrive was damaged and they were limping along on their emergency backup.

Comment: Makes sense! +1 and correct for being first!

Answer (score 15):

The Millenium Falcon's hyperdrive was not functioning correctly, and they were using a secondary drive to get to Bespin which was much slower than the main drive (see [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/27691/373) to a question about how the Falcon got to Bespin).

There's also the fact that Solo is talking in hyperbole - he's boasting about the Falcon, and isn't exactly a reliable source on the issue.

Comment: Good answer, too slow! +1 anyway

Comment: It *is* however established canon that the Millenium Falcon, when its hyperdrive is working properly, is faster than a star destroyer (and almost certainly an SSD...

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Kevin's answer as to how anyone could beat the Falcon to Bespin in the first place, there's also the fact that Boba Fett wouldn't need to take long to work out where he went:

1. The Falcon opted to hide in an asteroid field, then run and hide some more; therefore their hyperdrive was either nonfunctional or badly damaged (or they'd have hypered out way earlier).
2. Therefore, any jump they'll be capable of making would be very short range;
3. How many inhabited worlds are there in a short distance along the exit vector the Falcon used?
4. In that set, how many have sufficient starship repair facilities to fix a busted hyperdrive?
5. From that subset, which would be willing to provide *discreet* repairs to a ship that all but screams 'independent trader/smuggler' to anyone that looks at it?

Even in a big busy galaxy, it's entirely possible that that narrowed it down to Bespin and Cloud City even if Boba Fett knew nothing about Han Solo or his personal relationship with Lando Calrissian.

Comment: Hi Shadur, I think this is broadly addressed already in the questions opening: 'I understand that Boba Fett could have worked out the Falcon's destination from it's bearing/trajectory,'..also, could it be reworded to provide an answer as as it stands it is just a comment on another post...?