# What is the biggest display of power through the Force in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars, xkcd

I just read today's xkcd "what if" episode [How much Force power can Yoda output?](http://what-if.xkcd.com/3/).

In there, it is said that the biggest display of Force power is made by Yoda when he lifts the X-Wing out of the swamp in Dagobah. The article only takes into account the original trilogy, though.

I would be very interested in what the Force really could achieve at a maximum level. I remember, for example, that in Star Wars The Force Unleashed you stop an entire spaceship (an Imperial Star Destroyer in fact!) from falling down on you.

**So what is the biggest display of the Force in the Star Wars universe?**

I know this question might be closely related to [Who is the most powerful user of the Force?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/who-is-the-most-powerful-user-of-the-force-in-star-wars-canon), but that one has more of a different angle, as it asked for the *person that theoretically would be strongest* instead of an actual display of the Force.

Comment: This question is pretty subjective, any way to narrow it down?

Comment: Is it? Maybe I wasn't clear enough. I don't want any physical caluclations, but I mean "biggest display" in terms of physical power/force. Mind tricks etc not included.

Comment: I can just see this turning into a never ending supply from EU books. It will be hard to get a single irrefutable answer IMO.

Comment: Would you like that measured in joules, or the more familiar watt-hour?

Comment: [Galen Marek pulling an Imperial I-class Star Destroyer out of the sky and forcing it to the ground](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek#Force_powers) is impressive, but how much energy would he need to channel to do so? More than the [emperor when he exploded](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7644/45)? This might be unanswerable because there is too much unknown variables to compare feat.

Comment: @DavRob60 Additionally Kip Duron pulling the Sun Crusher out of the core of the gas giant Yavin must have taken tremendous effort.

Comment: @JackBNimble actually all he did was telekinetically manipulate the controls, and the ship flew itself out of the gas giant. Still impressive from so far away, but I don't think it was on a massive scale

Comment: In the scene where Yoda lifts the X-Wing, he also lectures Luke about how size doesn't matter...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are many notable displays of significant force powers in Star Wars. Most of them are seen through the works of the Expanded Universe. As most are never compared, and George Lucas to my knowledge has never "ranked" force events, here are some of the most powerful displays of the Force:

- Darth Nihilus could use the Force to feed off other Force users, encompassing entire planets and drain them of life ([source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darth_Nihilus#Powers_and_abilities))
- Emperor Palpatine supposedly used the Force to mind blank everyone who saw the burial of Lusankya under Coruscant's surface ([source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lusankya#Construction_and_placement_on_Coruscant))
- In death, Anakin Solo became a blinding pillar of light and was able to channel pure Force energy, fighting against overwhelming odds for far longer than should have been possible ([source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Anakin_Solo#Powers_and_abilities))
- "In arguably the finest display of telekinesis ever, Jedi Dorsk 81, utilizing the channeled Force powers of all available Jedi of Luke Skywalker's Jedi Praxeum, used telekinesis to push not one, but seventeen Imperial I-class Star Destroyers out of the Yavin system. The massive amount of Force energy claimed the Jedi's life." (direct quote from [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Telekinesis#Overview))
- The Sith Lord Naga Sadow was supposedly able to channel to force to cause a star to go supernova ([source 1](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naga_Sadow#The_Great_Hyperspace_War), [source 2](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Naga_Sadow#Powers_and_abilities))
- Cade Skywalker was able to use Dark Transfer to resurrect the dead, and other seemingly impossible acts ([source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cade_Skywalker#The_power_to_cheat_death))
- The Thought Bomb; it's an extremely powerful ancient Sith ritual. You can read about it [here](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Thought_bomb).
- Starkiller (Galen Marek) was able to pull a Star Destroyer down ([source](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galen_Marek#Force_powers)) (cheers to DavRob60)

I'm sure there are others, but these are some examples of extremely powerful force 'incidents'.

Comment: To be fair, Sadow actually moved the stars, not forced them to go supernova. When the two stars collided, that's when they went supernova. A good list, though. I came here specifically to mention Dorssk 81 but you already have it.

Comment: Someone freakin **MOVED** a star? They win, end of!

Comment: @Binary I know of a fanfic in which Palpatine pulled the entire *Milky Way* galaxy to enslave it and gather its resources.

Comment: Ah here, that's just ridonculous! :p

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(This is not your simple run of the mill spoiler. Proceed at your own risk)</sub>

In Episode 8: The Last Jedi:

> Luke Skywalker projected a *corporeal* Force Projection across half the galaxy. The strain of which was so much he died (like Yoda did in Episode 6, becoming a Force Ghost himself).

Further explanation

> We know he was corporeal because he held Leia's hand and kissed her forehead. This is definitely the most powerful show of The Force in Canon. And yes, I know the lightsaber did not hurt it, but as a projection, it could not, corporeal or otherwise.

Comment: What wounds? He didn't get wounded.

Comment: Yeah, I don't believe he was wounded in any way. It seemed to me Kylo's lightsaber went right through him - in fact, I don't think Kylo pressed the lightsaber into Luke to harm him, at that point, Kylo had already realized it was a trick and was trying hard not to believe that it was.

Comment: @RogueJedi, that wasn't a projection. That was a mind link.