# What is the exact information in SW canon regarding the speed of traversing the entire galaxy?

Tags: star-wars, canon

An excellent answer by @Daniel Bingham for " [Was the Millennium Falcon too slow?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/was-the-millennium-falcon-too-slow/1463#1463) " stated:

> Even with a well traveled hyperspace route **the fastest ships, such as the Millennium Falcon, would take several months to traverse the whole diameter of the galaxy.**
>
> Elsewhere the Galaxy was quoted as being 120,000 light years in diameter. ... Using that we can find that **a class 1/2 hyperdrive would travel at about 28 light years per hour.**

To which the [following comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/was-the-millennium-falcon-too-slow/1463#comment5767_1463) was posted:

> @Daniel your in-edit calculations are **off by a double order of magnitude**... **the travel times for crossing the galaxy in current canon are in double digit hours... not triple digit days**. WEG got it wrong in SW 1E, and LFL made them change it later. But then, as nick notes, Sci-Fi Writers have no sense of Scale. – aramis May 18 '11 at 17:44

**Question:**

What exactly is the canon source for the information in the comment? ("**the travel times for crossing the galaxy in current canon are in double digit hours**")

Comment: [Wookiepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Hyperdrive) says hours to days, but doesn't give a citation.

Comment: [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightspeed) says that a class 1 hyperdrive is over 100,000 times faster than the speed of light. Unfortunately, *we* seem to be the only source. Uh-oh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change from days to hours in WEG is noted in ***The Star Wars Rules Companion***, page 17, under the header "Astrogation" in the chapter *Starships*.

Designers notes (which ISTR being in *Star Wars Adventure Journal*) later mentioned that they'd guessed and gotten it wrong, and LFL required they correct it.

Note that later 3rd party sourcebooks also confirm hours, not days.

The crossing the galaxy in hours is from the ***Essential Atlas of the Star Wars Universe*** - I happened to have borrowed it from a friend, so I can't provide a page number for you. It does presume a well known route and a x1 hyperdrive in good repair.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at [this](http://www.starwarsmap.com/official_star_wars_galaxy_map_picture_image_photo_pic_pix_photograph/star_wars_map_star_wars_galaxy_map_official_galactic_map_star_wars_universe_1.jpg) map of the Star Wars galaxy, you can see that Endor, on the far left side, is about a quarter of the galactic diameter away from Sullust, directly to its right along the green path. [Sullust was the staging point](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_rendezvous_point#Battle_of_Endor) of the Rebel fleet before the Battle of Endor. And there is no indication in the film or novelization that the fleet traveled for any extended period of time. It appears that they may have had to kill a few tense hours, but they certainly weren't flying for days or weeks, as the lower speed estimate would require.