# Which sci-fi universe has the slowest extensively used interstellar drive (best available)?

Tags: ftl-drive

This is sort of the opposite of this question: [Which SciFi universe has the fastest space ships (hyperspace technology)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/which-scifi-universe-has-the-fastest-space-ships-hyperspace-technology)

Since the obvious answer is just wherever there is no technology much more advanced than our own, we need to modify the question.

In order to force a unique answer, the metric we will use is:
In which universe, despite having slow drive technology, have people traveled the farthest and spread over the most worlds using non-FTL drive ?   The non-FTL drive has to be used because it is the fastest drive available, not for some quirky exceptional case.  I.e. no one has FTL.

Obviously teleport-type technologies etc. are not allowed.  There is no cheating.

Comment: I would have created tags like non-ftl-drive rocket ion-drive etc, but I don't have enough rep.

Comment: Our universe.  :(

Comment: @Keen be positive. Just because the humans in our universe have very slow (inter)stellar drives doesn't meant that there isn't some other race out there with something faster.

Comment: This question could potentially spawn any number of lists of works, each one trying to out do the rest. It may be helpful to place additional restrictions on it, as the linked question did by asking specifically about TV shows.

Comment: I see two questions here: which universe has the slowest travel speed, and which universe has traveled the furthest despite slow speeds and long travel times.  I think it needs to be one or the other, not both.

Comment: @Beofett Asking which universe has the slowest travel speed is pointless.  Like Keen pointed out (and me too implicitly) the answer is our universe (or at least any universe similar to ours where it is definitely established that there are no aliens with better technology).

Or if you want to get even more technical, a universe inhabited only by turtles or no life that can move at all...   but come on, you get the gist.

Comment: @ThePopMachine Then the question needs to be clarified further, I think. AFAIK, interstellar travel isn't really part of our universe.  Perhaps "furthest distance traveled at sub-light speeds", or "longest duration interstellar journey (with passengers)" would be better wordings?

Comment: @Beofett:   Reread the question.  I didn't say anything about our universe there except to explain why the question isn't just, Where is the slowest travel?  You're right that technically slowest, most distance, and most time can result in different answers, but I don't really think it's necessary to overconstrain the question.  If someone said, "In this book, people only had ion drive and they spread over the entire galaxy over the course of 50 million years"  that would be an answer.

Comment: @ThePopMachine If there's multiple valid answers, then it probably needs to be fixed.  What happens if one answer is "they traveled 5 million lightyears doing 1/4 speed of light" and another is "they travelled 1 million lightyears doing 1/8 speed of light"?  Which one is right?  Or are both "right", in which case this is asking for a list of answers?

Comment: @Beofett:  Yes, I understand the point.  I just think it is a technicality in this case.  But I will clarify to be within the rules.  We will go for farthest traveled using conventional drive in a non-FTL universe.

Comment: [The Millenium Falcon was pretty slow](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1458/was-the-millennium-falcon-too-slow)!

Comment: This question still needs further fixing before it becomes answerable. As it is, it still has potentially conflicting criteria (furthest traveled/spread over the most worlds), and has conditions not detailed in the actual question (i.e. can't be accidental, must be in widespread use, etc.).

Comment: Modestly or barely relativistic interstellar civilizations are a dime a dozen. Universes where a highly technological planetary civilization can only afford small scale interstellar (i.e. no colonization to speak of) travel are less common, but I'm sure I can run down several examples just in my library. Start with Forward's *Rocheworld*.

Comment: There's a short-short story where they discover Hyperspace, but the speed of light there is slower than in our universe, not faster.

Comment: Question/title is pretty confused.  I can see two different questions - which universe makes the most extensive use of a slow transport system (leaving open options of FTL and even very fast drives) or which universe with no FTL travel has the most extensive spread.  I think to confusion comes from the use of the terms 'slow drive' and 'non FTL' as synonyms(?)

Comment: @NPSF3000: Often it's not possible to make a question absolutely clear in the short space of the title.   That's why there's main text.      Aside,  in this case the "(best available)" is attempting to clarify.

Comment: Ten years later:   Voting to repopen.   There are upvotes and answers with many upvotes.   No real reason for this to still be closed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Larry Niven's Known Space stories, much of early Human Space was colonized with a combination of two different STL technologies.  These were:

- Ramrobots (automated crewless [Bussard Ramjets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet))
- Slowboats (large slow fusion powered ships that carry the colonists).

The Ramrobots perform the initial scouting of potential colonies, and can be used to refuel the Slowboats. The colonists are usually held in suspended animation (when stasis fields are discovered in '[World of Ptavvs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_of_Ptavvs)').  Colonization takes decades of effort.

Using this method the following Known Space colonies are founded:

- Jinx (Sirius A)
- Wunderland (Alpha Centuri)
- We Made It (Procyon A)
- Plateau (Tau Ceti)
- Home (Epsilon Indi)

Many of Niven's novels and short stories are set in a time before Hyperdrive with primarily fusion powered reaction drive STL ships. Humankind develop some extremely efficient fusion engines and you get everything from 1-crew Singleships to giant interstellar Slowboats.

Comment: Look elsewhere--while they don't colonize, look at the Outsiders.  No FTL yet they apparently cover the galaxy.

Comment: @LorenPechtel - but in ships which accelerate to just below lightspeed using an inertialess drive - so not the slowest drive.

Comment: Outsiders have hyperdrives. Mentioned in Ringworld Engineers.

Comment: @aramis - Outsiders sold the hyperdrive to humans, but they do not use hyperdrive themselves.  The wikipedia article on them says 'rarely use them' - but what I have read (in particular the story Flatlander) implies that they never use them to the point of almost being afraid.  I recall reading that even asking them the questions 'why they do not use hyperspace?' and 'why do they follow starseeds?' are priced so high as to be unafordable even to the likes of Gregory Pelton.

Comment: Even after obtaining the hyperdrive, at 3 1/2 days per light year, it takes some time to get anywhere that matters.  Earth to the Ringworld or Eath to the galactic core would have been longer than a human lifetime (without boosterspice).  Quantum II hyperdrive solved that, but wasn't cost-effective for normal travel.

Answer (score 20):

Two examples from Alastair Reynolds:

- In the [Revelation Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revelation_Space_universe) universe, there is no FTL, and in the far-future of the setting the Greenfly are implied to have spread over most of the galaxy and eventually the [observable universe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactic_North).
- In [House of Suns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Suns) humanity has settled the entire galaxy over the course of 6 million years of slower-than-light travel.

Answer (score 16):

To address the "slowest interstellar travel speed", I propose the novel [Footfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Footfall).

In the novel, the aliens travel from the [Alpha Centauri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_Centauri) system, a little over 4 light years away from earth.  It takes them 61 years to reach our solar system in a ship powered by a [Bussard ramjet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bussard_ramjet).

To address the "furthest distance traveled without FTL being a possibility", The [Red Dwarf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Dwarf) traveled for [3 million years](http://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/ngdl5/how_far_could_one_get_if_a_ship_travelled/) (ship's time) at near-light speed.

Comment: I want to say Red Dwarf is a winner.  But:
(1) it was accidental that Lister was asleep for 3 million years
(2) it wasn't routine
(3) on a technicality: I'm no Red Dwarf expert, but among all the quirky things that happened on Red Dwarf there must've been teleportation and/or FTL

Comment: @ThePopMachine I believe (from the Wikipedia article) that teleportation and/or FTL were introduced in the series sometime during or after the 7th season.  The 3 million years of travel occurred prior to the first season, though, when FTL and teleportation were not options (so, per your question, the non-FTL drive was used because it was the fastest drive available).

Comment: It wasn't "used" for three million years because it was the fastest drive.  One character just failed was in suspended animation, so he drifted for three million years.  This is not a drive.

Comment: Actually, the ship's computer *kept* him in suspended animation for 3 million years until the radiation danger was gone. I don't recall anything saying they were drifting. In fact, the [episode description](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Red_Dwarf_episodes) for season 1 episode 2 specifically states "Red Dwarf has been steadily accelerating for three million years".

Comment: Still not intentional use for 3 million years and still not extensive use.

Comment: I didn't realize from your question that those were requirements....

Answer (score 12):

Well, how about Poul Anderson's "Tau Zero" for maximum distance traveled.

In this tale we have a basic sublight interstellar ramjet with a malfunction which prevents slowdown until repared. Meanwhile, they keep accelerating, pushing time dilation way *way* down, hence the book's title.

Eventually they fix their problem, but have been flying around long enough to witness the heat-death and eventual collapse of the universe, and they enter the next cycle of the universe's expansion. A great many trillions of years of time elapsed, all of it moving at just a hair under speed of light.

Answer (score 10):

In the universe of Ender's Game, space travel is done using ships which travel at almost the speed of light. Time dilation means that while it takes decades of "real" time for a ship to move between planets, for the travelers only a few weeks have passed.

Comment: "Almost the speed of light" is still pretty fast.  There must be a far-reaching universe where only realistic conventional drives exist, and people have spread out over tens of millions of years.

Comment: Also, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_in_the_Ender%27s_Game_series:

Instantaneous Travel - A simple spacecraft is constructed (later deemed unnecessary due to Jane's precision in transportation), and through holding the image of the traveler in her consciousness, Jane can pick up the image and place it anywhere in the universe instantly. This advancement is threatened by Congress' attempt to deactivate her "program." Found in Children of the Mind. This concept was introduced in the later chapters of Xenocide and necessary for its ending.

Comment: Le Guin's Ekumen also had nearly-as-fast-as-light travel, but ftl communications by means of the *ansible*...Looks like Card pretty much adopted this combination straight out of her work.

Comment: @ThePhoton Indeed, in Ender's Game, when the ansible is first described its name is said to be taken out of "some old science fiction book", or similar phrase.  A clear homage.

Comment: @ThePopMachine simple acceleration to almost the speed of light would seem make more sense in those circumstances (over thousands or millions of years) than "realistic" propulsion drives.

Answer (score 7):

In *Return from the Stars* from Stanisław Lem, the protagonist and crew return from a mission to Arcturus (36.7 light-years) which took 127 years (10 years for them due to time-dilation).

In the original, Polish version they travel to another star instead, which is only 25 light-years away (the travel also takes 127 years).

It is strongly hinted that there is no other sentient life in the Galaxy, and that humanity will abandon space travel forever (or at least for a long, long time).

Comment: I haven't read it, but those numbers seem inconsistent. 127 years to Arcturus and back implies an average speed of about 0.58c (0.39c for the original Polish version), which isn't nearly fast enough for that kind of time dilation. Can you recheck the numbers? Or is there some other kind of time dilation going on?

Comment: @KeithThompson : I don't remember it being discussed in detail in the book, but I guess if they accelerated to almost light-speed in a year or two, then decelerated using a similar time-frame, and were flying at constant higher-than-0.58c in the meantime, it could be plausible to attain such a time dilation. Or, it might be an author oversight, as the travel itself and its destination is not important for the story. The story is set after they arrived back to Earth, and the only plot-relevant thing is that they didn't find anything interesting in space, and that a lot of time went by on Earth.

Answer (score 6):

Depends what you mean by "people".  In "The Fourth Profession" by Larry Niven, the (alien) Monks have an extensive interstellar trade that uses ships driven only by light sails.  Normally, they demand a launching laser from their customers.  If they don't get one, they trigger the star to go nova. Either way implies a pretty low max achievable speed.

Answer (score 6):

[Schild's Ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schild's_Ladder) by Greg Egan involves near-lightspeed travel for hundreds of years in an attempt to escape a bubble in space that isn't very friendly to life and expands in every direction at half the speed of light.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few universes where there is interstellar sublight travel. Sometimes it is even mixed with FTL travel, or else it is a necessary precursor to the universe's development of FTL drive tech.

- In the *Star Trek* universe, the first fictional Enterprise was a sublight interstellar ship, ECV-330, from the 2100s. Humans have since gained FTL technologies in several variations.
- In the *Star Wars* universe, hyperdrives are the primary means of interstellar travel, but it is apparently still feasible to travel at sublight speeds to get places. The Millenium Falcon, for example, travels from the Anoad system to the Bespin system with a broken hyperdrive.
- In the Riddick universe (*Pitch Black*, *Chronicles of Riddick*), humans travel from system to system on sleeper ships. It takes months to get places, but various space lanes are well-established and well-traveled.
- In the *Avatar* universe, humans have a fledgling space ferry system between Earth and Pandora (and probably other closer places) using sleeper ships. A trip between Earth and Pandora takes a little more than 5 years.
- In the computer game *Sid Meier's Alpha Centauri*, a colony ship is sent from Earth and takes 7 years to arrive at its destination, Planet, in orbit around the Alpha Centauri binary system, travelling under relatively conventional propulsion. This is by no means an everyday occurrence; the launching of the ship is a last-ditch effort to save humanity from an unsalvageable Earth.
- Similarly, the game *Freelancer* has its backstory in the endgame of *Starlancer*, where the Alliance (made up of 5 member Earth nations: America, Britain, Germany, Spain and Japan) sends a fleet of sleeper ships to the Sirius Sector to escape its war with the Coalition (made up of other former Earth nations). The ships travel quite fast as evidenced by the intro movie, but according to in-game story material, the ships are only near-light-speed, hence the need for cryosleep. The game itself uses FTL travel in the form of Jump Gates, but no ship can travel FTL without them.
- Ender's universe as previously stated uses ships travelling near-light-speed, dealing with the relativity concerns and other concerns as Einstein predicted we'd have to, but using entanglement to provide FTL communication (which science has since disproven; the interactions of quantum entanglement do not exceed light speed).

Most other universes in which FTL travel doesn't exist generally confine travel to members of our own solar system, primarily Earth, Venus, Mars and various moons of the gas giants. Arthur C. Clarke posited several ideas at various stages of human technological evolution; in *2001* and *2010*, humans used fission-powered ion drives with cryo-sleep to reduce food usage. In *Imperial Earth*, we'd colonized a lot of the solar system using ships powered by controlled singularities. These allow travel between Saturn and Earth over a period of about 3 weeks, during which the ship is constantly under power either accelerating or decelerating along its course. By *3001*, humans have discovered anti-gravity propulsion, and mining asteroids beyond the orbit of Pluto is relatively commonplace, but we're still not travelling between stars on a regular basis. I remember a Russian sci-fi novel translated into English, in which humans possess a technology that allows for relatively speedy travel within the solar system but does not work for interstellar trips. I read it in high school and have since forgotten the name.

Comment: Has anyone considered Firefly?

Comment: [Building Harlequin's Moon](http://www.amazon.com/Building-Harlequins-Moon-Larry-Niven/dp/0765351293/ref=sr_1_sc_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325886196&sr=1-1-spell) and [Old Twentieth](http://www.amazon.com/Old-Twentieth-Joe-Haldeman/dp/0441013430/ref=sr_1_8?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1325886154&sr=1-8) also feature cultures (humans) using STL ships, although these books focus more on the journey rather than the destination.

Comment: Also, Orson Scott Card's Homecoming series has a human civilization that colonizes a number of planets using sub-light sleeper ships (the number 12 sits in my head, but I am not 100% certain on this).

Comment: @Adele I believe the entire Firefly "universe" takes place in a single (extremely large) solar system known as the "Verse", so it really doesn't qualify as interstellar travel.

Comment: @Beofett Fair enough.

Comment: -1: multiple incorrect statements. SW starships routinely have a backup hyperdrive; Riddic ships have some form of hyperdrive (and if you'd dug around the DVD, you'd know it took mere weeks for Riddick to cross between systems); SMAC is a sequel to SM's Civilization...

Comment: @aramis - if the Falcon had a backup hyperdrive they wouldn't be in the trouble they were in for most of ESB; they could have rendezvoused with the fleet instead of trying to get their hyperdrive working. Pitch Black opens with the ship carrying Riddick (and all other characters of the movie) approaching the system at clearly sublight speeds (it would make sense for the ships to have hyperdrive, but we never see it). And I never said SMAC wasn't a spinoff of Civ.

Comment: @keithS since the Falcon DOES have one according to sources going back to before ESB, albeit a VERY slow one (x10 - as slow as the Death Star's hyperdrive).... As for Pitch Black: Many Sci-Fi systems of FTL don't work in-system; the travel times given on the DVD put inter-system travel times in days. Which means there must be FTL.

Answer (score 5):

The universe in the Passages series: http://localroger.com/. The entire epos is pretty much devoid of far out sci fi tech, except for a form of strong AI.

Answer (score 5):

If your star travelers don't have to be human then I think the all time slowest interstellar voyagers are the aliens in Hal Clement's novel The Nitrogen Fix. They use hollowed out comets as their ships. I don't recall Clement specifying their means of propulsion but it was probably something slow like a gravitational slingshot. Their ships drift from one star system to the next and scan it for planets habitable for their species. If there are none they settle into that system's Oort cloud and wait for such a planet to evolve!

Comment: If you're going for non-human colonisation, you can do much better than that. Niven's [Stage Trees](http://larryniven.wikia.com/wiki/Stage_Tree) gain orbit from the ground, then drift through space for (potentially) tens of millions of years before landing, breeding and starting a new cycle. They've colonised millions of worlds, all at 0.0000000000000001% of lightspeed

Comment: Stage Trees are non-sentient and thus are more a form of panspermia than interstellar colonists. If humanity ever perfects suspended animation like Hal Clement's aliens we could colonize the entire galaxy with ships no faster than the Voyager probes. Equip comets with nuclear-thermal rocket engines using cometary mass for propellant, slingshot past several planets to reach solar system escape velocity and just coast.

Answer (score 3):

In the [Saga of Seven Suns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Saga_of_Seven_Suns) books by Kevin J. Anderson, the first inter-stellar ships launched from Earth were 11 'generation' ships, where a number of generations of people lived aboard the ships, that moved sub-light-speed, until they were either found by the Ildiran race, or they stopped at the place that eventually becomes known as Rendezvous.  The generation ships were in space for a couple of hundred years (I forget the exact length of time).  Technically, when the Ildirans find them, they take them to new colony planets using the Ildiran's FTL ships, so not sure this fulfuls your question's limitations or not...

EDIT: Just checked: The Ildirans intercept the first generation ship 144 years after it departs Earth.  The Roamers, however, stop themselves, in the Meyer rubble belt which becomes known as Rendezvous, after 96 years.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Chronicles of Solace](http://www.sff.net/people/roger.allen/bookpage/solace.htm) series by Roger Allen McBride?  Humans confined by lightspeed, but to get around crazy time involved, they have temporal wormholes (Time shafts) that drop you back X years in time.  Thus the net time loss to a person involved is small, and the distance is covered.

The poor ship however is like Marvin the paranoid Android at the Restaurant at the End of the Universe.

Then there are temporal guards who make sure no one abuses the time shafts for real time travel.

Answer (score 1):

Zones of Thought from Vernor Vinge. Portions of the Galaxy have physical rules that do not permit "fantastic" technology. Away from the edge of the Milky Way Galaxy, toward the core, is the "Slow Zone" (where earth would be located). A Deepness in the Sky takes place in this area and the book discusses some of the problems of trying to maintain an interstellar trading culture without access to superluminal travel or to superluminal communication. The physical dimensions of the starfaring culture is not explicitly stated and neither the speeds as far as I can recall, but they do require either suspended animation or longevity technology to make the journeys.

Comment: The novel makes it clear that the web of intergalactic civilization extends practically to the rim of the galaxy, with the realm beyond being where outrageously advanced things live. From that, I think we can estimate the physical dimensions to be around ~2/3 the radius of the Milky Way.