# What is the Millennium Falcon's power source?

Tags: star-wars, millennium-falcon

We know that the Millennium Falcon is so fast that it "*made the Kessel Run in less than twelve parsecs*" according to Han Solo.

A fast ship needs a good power source, however, so **what is the Millennium Falcon's power source?**

Comment: It has Einstein constantly turning in his coffin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Quadex Power Core

According to [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Quadex_power_core), the Falcon was given the Power Core while it was owned by Unkar Plutt on Jakku.

Although I must point out this was not the Power Core that did the Kessel Run, that was just your good ol' friendly neighbourhood **Power Core**.

The following image is found in the TFA: Incredible Cross-sections.

[image: Power core]

From the original films we're just told there's a power core, but nothing about what type of core it was.

[image: Old school core.]

Comment: What about the time of the Kessel Run?

Comment: @Gallifreyan Just because a unit of distance was ignorantly used as a unit of time, we do not need to try to pretend that the statement meant anything other than gosh-wow bafflegab.

Comment: @sabbahillel He meant because the answer I've given is the power core at a time after the Battle of Endor.

Comment: Isn't the kessel Run an asteroid field? Measuring it in distance shows skill in navigation as it is shorter

Comment: At the risk of shamless self promotion, I broke down the speed of the Kessel Run [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158276/how-long-did-it-take-the-millennium-falcon-to-do-the-kessel-run/158494#158494)

Comment: @amflare queue the downvotes!