# How did Han Solo use the Maw Cluster to beat the Kessel Run?

Tags: star-wars, physics, millennium-falcon, han-solo

We know that Solo made the Kessel Run in a shorter distance by skirting close to the Maw Cluster (with the help of his Class 0.5 modified hyperdrive and navicomputer), but how exactly does the physics of it work?

Did he use one of the black holes of the Maw Cluster in a high-risk gravity assist, like I suspect, or was it by some other means?

Comment: The physics of it is that a parsec is a measure of distance (about 3.26 light-years) and not time.

Comment: Does it matter to you whether or not we are somehow measuring this in parsecs, or are you essentially asking "how did Han Solo manage to make that run better than other pilots?" You might want to avoid mentioning parsecs, just to make it easier for people to get to the real question.

Comment: @Blackwood, I am well aware that "parsec" is a unit of distance. That is not relevant to the question.

Comment: https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Kessel_Run/Legends (or [google 'kessel run in 12 parsecs'](https://www.google.com/search?q=kessel+run+in+12+parsecs)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kessel Run in 12 parsecs: screenplay error, or part of the movie?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20359/kessel-run-in-12-parsecs-screenplay-error-or-part-of-the-movie)

Comment: @Jeeped I am specifically interested in the *physics* of it.

Comment: @Chromanyx Questions specifically seeking scientific explanations are generally considered off-topic here.  It would need to be canon-compatible one way or another.

Comment: @MishaR how so? the question seems in line with other questions using the *physics* tag.

Comment: @Chromanyx Depends on whether the physics you are looking for is compatible with an in-universe explanation.  If you hover your cursor over the physics tag, it will tell you the same thing.

Comment: @MishaR I am specifically looking for the related physics of *Star Wars*. It is clear that people here would rather argue about parsecs or whether I actually specified Star Wars than actually answer the question. Good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, this isn't entirely about top speed - it's also about acceleration.  A rocket (or other propelled object, such as a YT-1300 Corellian Light Freighter) does not need to reach [escape velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_velocity) to exit a gravity well, but it does need to overcome the acceleration due to [gravity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity).

Since gravity is inversely proportional to the square of distance, a ship with a higher maximum acceleration can get "deeper" and still escape.  For example, if it takes an acceleration of 4 [kellicams per lup<sup>2</sup>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klingon_language) to escape at 5 units from an object's centre of mass, then it takes only 1 kellicams per lup<sup>2</sup> at 10 units, 6.25 kellicams per lup<sup>2</sup> at 4 units from the object's centre of mass, or a whopping **100** kellicams per lup<sup>2</sup> at 1 unit.

As such, a ship with 60% more acceleration (in this case of 5-units out) can cut 1 unit closer to the object without crashing and burning.  Much like a [racing line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racing_line) on a corner, this is a shorter distance.

A ship moving sufficiently fast can 'lose' more speed to gravity and maintain an escape velocity, which allows it to slip closer to the stellar mass than pure acceleration would allow it to - so long as it is able to get back out far enough for acceleration to overcome gravity before it stops.  A bit like taking a run-up versus a standing jump.  This is essentially a [flyby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyby_(spaceflight))

Comment: This actually makes sense. The Falcon's upgraded class 0.5 hyperdrive would have enabled it to accelerate much faster than other smuggler ships, and thus make a much closer cut around the Maw.

Comment: Friendly reminder to downvoters:  if you have a problem with the answer, *please let me know*, so that I can determine if it is systemic or something that can be addressed.  (The common-sense exception being if you up-vote someone else's comment that explains your reason for downvoting)